is there a way to undo actions of a command in r program. i executed a command that made a change in my dataframe and now i want to undo that change
i executed a command that changed my dataframe now i want to change my dataframe like before the command
i tried to erase the command and run it again but no results
i removed some letters and digits form my column but i accidentally removed some wanted letters now i want to change it back

Where does the data.frame come from? Can't you recreate it from the beginning?

Generally speaking R command changes the dataframe in a way you asked in your command. That dataframe resides in RAM and changes are instantaneous. However the "undo" process is relatively easy - you start with the original data and run the commands up until the command that did not do what you wanted it to do. Then you change the command and see if the results are what you want.
The only way how changes would be permanent is - if you read this dataframe from a file, then after you offending command you overwrote the original file (which would take at least one more command).
Common strategies are to make copies of the original data (e.g. as another file on disk). Quite often for each processing stage the dataframe is copied into a new dataframe and further operations are done on that. Due to the interactive nature of R it is very rare that one would make changes and immediately overwrite the input file.
# example of commands and new frames
InitDataFrame %>% str_replace_all("[aeiou]", "x")
# gives you output on console
InitData.no_wowels <- InitDataFrame %>% str_replace_all("[aeiou]", "x")
# gives you new data frame which you can use in next processing steps
# of course, you would not do that if your data frames are VERY big.

If you want more help, you could update your question with the command that gave results you did not like.
